# Handling http response codes in GetStringAsync

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

i'm very new to C#, let alone Windows Phone development :)

I'm trying to send a request, get the JSON response, but if there is an error (such as 401), be able to tell the user such.  Here is my code:

```
async Task<string> AccessTheWebAsync()
        {
            //builds the credentials for the web request
            var credentials = new NetworkCredential(globalvars.username, globalvars.password);
            var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credentials };

            //calls the web request, stores and returns JSON content
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
            Task<string> getStringTask = client.GetStringAsync("https://www.bla.com/content");

            String urlContents = await getStringTask;

            return urlContents;

        }
```

I know it must be something I'm doing wrong in the way that I send the request and store the response...but i'm just not sure what.

If there is an error, I get a general:
net_http_message_not_success_statuscode

Thank you!

Comment: If you want to have a better control use the HttpWebRequest instead. With it you can get all the info about the error and even read the error respose body.

Comment: I'm sorry, could you give me an example of how i could use that instead of what I have above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using an HttpClient use a plain good old HttpWebRequest :)

```
    async Task<string> AccessTheWebAsync()
    {

        HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.CreateHttp("http://example.com/nodocument.html");
        req.Method = "GET";
        req.Timeout = 10000;
        req.KeepAlive = true;

        string content = null;
        HttpStatusCode code = HttpStatusCode.OK;

        try
        {
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)await req.GetResponseAsync())
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                    content = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();

                code = response.StatusCode;
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {

            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response)
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                    content = sr.ReadToEnd();

                code = response.StatusCode;
            }

        }

        //Here you have now content and code.

        return content;

    }
```

Comment: I did try that, but the problem i'm hitting now is that GetResponse() doesn't appear to be available on WinPhone...   There is getResponseAsync(), but still trying to figure out how to use that..

Comment: @Gusman love it. Can't count the amount of times, I've swapped out HttpClient for a GOF HttpWebRequest.

Comment: Does not answer for HttpHandler and instead prescribes a solution that is different from the requested answer

Answer (score 36):

You could use te GetAsync() method instead of the GetStringAsync().

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://www.bla.com/content");

if(!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
     if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
     {
         do something...
     }
}
String urlContents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

This way you can make use of the HttpStatusCode enumerable to check the returned status code.

Comment: What's the point of calling the `GetAsync` if you're going to synchronously wait for the result with `.Result` in the same line of code? Submitted an edit.